# After updating Android Studio 3.0 Stable and i migrate my project in new gradle i am facing issue while build

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android Studio 3.0 stable version from 2.3.3 my previous project working fine but after updating to new gradle I am facing this issue.

[image]

I already tried many solutions but did not get success

- I tried to rebuild ,clean and build
- I tried to setting `android:enableAapt2=false`

Comment: android studio invalidate caches and restart after build project

Comment: i already tried but there is no effect.

Comment: Open SDK Manager >> install default require packages (remember : don't check or uncheck any other packages just accept licence term and install it) >> after restart system and studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is some problem with your nine patch images if you are using.
Try to correct the error from nine-patch image.
May this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944050/meaning-of-red-color-in-androids-nine-patch-drawables) will help you