# I can't understand something about Draw9patch.bat

Tags: android, patch

When I use the  Draw9patch.bat.
What's the meaning of "layout bounds"?
Draw "layout bounds" for what?!
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 9 Patch tool: What is the new layout bounds feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406521/android-9-patch-tool-what-is-the-new-layout-bounds-feature)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#UI explains it with some details, if you hit CTRL while painting in the border regions you draw those small red pixels.